# Can't install drupal 8 commerce checkout module

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I'm trying to install `drupal 8 commerce` checkout module, but I'm getting the error:

> Unable to install Commerce Checkout due to unmet dependencies:
>   core.entity_view_display.commerce_product_variation.default.summary
>   (commerce_product.commerce_product_variation_type.default)

I can't find the problem, what it could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we have a soft-dependency issue on Commerce Product. Please install Commerce Product first. This is an issue due to the default checkout summary.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by creating a product variation "Default" I had deleted the variation that was there by default when setting up commerce.

Comment: There must be a better way to check module presence, if really necessary :) 
An issue exists: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3057081

Answer (score 0):

You can install commerce module with all components using composer:

```
cd /path/to/drupal8
composer require "drupal/commerce"
```

You also can install individual components with composer e.g

```
cd /path/to/drupal8
composer require "drupal/commerce_authnet"
```

Try to install this module in this way. :)

Comment: This issue is not about Composer. It's about an error message that occurs when installing via drush/drupal console.