# Cant Install Commerce Checkout Module

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I'm in the process of upgrading my website from Drupal 7 to 8 and one of my tasks is to ensure that all modules are copied over and installed.

I've been able to install every 'Commerce' module apart from the checkout.

> Unable to install Commerce Checkout due to unmet dependencies: 
>   core.entity_view_display.commerce_product_variation.default.summary 
>   (commerce_product.commerce_product_variation_type.default)

This question was asked and answered here: [Can't install drupal 8 commerce checkout module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694268/cant-install-drupal-8-commerce-checkout-module)

However, it does not help me because I've already used Composer to install the commerce module but I still cant enable it.

---

```
$ composer require drupal/commerce
Using version ^2.5 for drupal/commerce
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

---

```
$ composer require drupal/commerce_checkout
Using version ^2.5 for drupal/commerce_checkout
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

---

```
$ composer require drupal/commerce_product
Using version ^2.5 for drupal/commerce_product
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

---

I appreciate any solutions that you may have and look forward to discussing this issue with you further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you already fixed the issue yourself simply by "installing" `drupal/commerce` first.

The three snippets you provided at the end of your question look fine and actually just says they are already "installed". Composer downloaded everything for you and now you just have to **enable** them via `drush` or from the UI.

---

Now I got it. This error message occurs when installing Commerce Checkout via drush/drupal console (or maybe even via the UI). And it says it requires a display or view mode from the Commerce Product entity type. Then I guess the second answer in the linked question is right: install Commerce Product first as that may provide the missing display upon installation.

Even if that doesn't work you may circumvent the issue by creating the display or view mode manually yourself.

Comment: Yes, all that's left to do is enable them - you are correct. However, when I try to do so, I get the error message above (yellow box).

Comment: @CraigyCraigo - Ah now I get it. Checkout requires a display that is provided by Commerce Product. Did you try to enable Commerce Product first, too?